# ASP.NET Razor: routing, tabel for loop bug

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, html-table

[image]

In the above table, the first (+) option routes to the wrong path.

It's supposed to redirect to Home\UpdateField. But when I click the first row, it just refreshes the current page. All other rows work fine.

```
@RedeemPage.Fields.Count
                    @foreach (var item in RedeemPage.Fields) {
                        using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateField", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = @RedeemPage.Id }))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="field_name" id="field_name" value="@item.Name" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="field_type" id="field_type">
                                        <option value="Text" selected="selected">Text</option>
                                        <option value="TextArea">Text Area</option>
                                        <option value="Hidden">Hidden field</option>
                                        <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="field_required" id="field_required" checked="@item.Required"/> </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="field_value" id="field_value" value="@item.Value" /></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="" style="width:26px;height:26px;background: transparent url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/prettyoffice/24/add1-.png);background-position:center;border:none;"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="" style="width:26px;height:26px;background: transparent url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/24x24/Close_Box_Red.png);background-position:center;border:none;"/>
                            </tr>
                        }
                     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the table was inside another form. Fixed it.